# .NET MAUI MediaPicker CaptureVideo camera resolution

Tags: ios, maui

I am currently building an app for IOS with .NET Maui. The idea is to first make the app available for IOS and later for Android.

It is essential for the app to shoot high quality images and video's.
I just started the project this week and I am playing around to try some key functionalities.

The problem I am facing is that the MediaPicker doesnt seem to use the device camera with all the functionalities the camera has. The biggest issue is the quality/resolution of the video.

For capturing a video I have so far the following code:

```
if (MediaPicker.IsCaptureSupported)
{
    FileResult file = await MediaPicker.CaptureVideoAsync();
    
    if (file != null)
    {
        _localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, file.FileName);
        using Stream srcStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
        using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(_localFilePath);
        await srcStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);
        
        mediaElement.Source = MediaSource.FromFile(_localFilePath);
        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(TestLabel.Text);
    }
}
else
{
    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Oops..", "Your device is not supported", "Ok");
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to get a better video/image resolution in a Maui app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no api to ajust camera resolution for MediaPicker now. You may raise a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

From Apple Docs, `UIImageController` has [videoQuality](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619154-videoquality?language=objc).

> The various video qualities are listed in the UIImagePickerControllerQualityType enumeration. The default value is UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium. To capture or transcode a movie using a video quality other than the default value, you must set the quality explicitly.

You may see from Maui [MediaPicker source](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/2583c1c1920fbc3d773d1fb5852d524694733c8c/src/Essentials/src/MediaPicker/MediaPicker.ios.cs#L71), it doesn't set the `VideoQuality` for picker. So I think it uses the default value which is `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium`.

One of the workarounds I can think of is to implement your own MediaPicker. That is to say, after you create your own `UIImageController` and set like below,

```
var picker = new UIImagePickerController();
picker.VideoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityType.High;
```

I don't think it an easy work. Maui MediaPicker [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Essentials/src/MediaPicker/MediaPicker.ios.cs) may help you.

Comment: Hallo, thanks for your answer. This is what I did indeed and it works fine.